# Create combined client side and server side validation in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, validation, symfony-forms

I think it would be very useful to create client side form validation up on the symfony2 `Form` and `Validator` components.

The best way to do this would be to pass the validation constraints to the form view.
With that information it would be possible to make a template that renders a form field to something like this:

```
<div>
    <label for="form_email">E-Mail</label>
    <input 
        id="form_email" type="text" name="form[email]" value=""
        data-validation-constraints='{"NotBlank":{},"MinLength":{"limit":6}}'
    />
</div>
```

The JavaScript part then would be to find all `<input>` elements that have the `data-validation-constraints` attribute and create the correct validation for them.

To pass the validation constraints to the form view i thought the best way would be to create a form type extension. That's the point of my Question: **Is this the correct way? And how is this possible?**

At the Moment my form type extension looks like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class FieldTypeExtension extends \Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension{

    public function getExtendedType(){
        return 'field';
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form)
    {
        // at this point i didn't find a way to get the 
        // validation constraints out of the $form
        // the `getAllValidationConstraints` here is just an example
        $view->set('validation_constraints', $form->getAllValidationConstraints());
    }

}
```

**How can i get all validation constraints applied to one form field out of the FormInterface object?**

Comment: @alessandro1997 this bundle tries to solve the same problem as i described, but in a very different way. It works currently only with constraints defined in annotations in the entity. I want to get all constraints, no matter where they came from. I want to use the same mechanism to find the constaints as the `isValid` method uses.

Answer (score 2):

Check the corresponding open issue ["[Form] JavaScript validation"](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4383) which contains a reference to SimpleThingsFormExtraBundle (or rather a specific, open PR of that bundle) that does that.

Answer (score 1):

This is new Symfony 2 bundle which converts form type constraints to JavaScript validation rulers https://github.com/formapro/JsFormValidatorBundle

Answer (score 0):

You can do something simplier:

The FieldType already passes a **attr** attribute to the form which is directly passed as **attr** var to view. You had better to modify this **attr** form's attribute in order to add your **data-validation-constraints** attribute because it will avoid you to be required to also customize the form theme to handle your new var.

```
<?php

namespace MyBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class FieldTypeJsValidationExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $attr = $builder->getAttribute('attr');
        $attr = array_merge(
            array(
                'data-validation-constraints' => $this->aMethodThatRenderTheFinalContentOfTheValidationAttribute(),
            ),
            $builder->getAttribute('attr')
        );

        $builder->setAttribute('attr', $attr);
    }

    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return 'field';
    }

}
```

Comment: You are using the buildForm method. At this point you have no reference to the FormInterface object. I think i will need a reference to this object to get all the constraints of the current form field. But i am not sure...
My question was how to get all validation constraints applied to one form field out of the FormInterface object